# Op-amp as constant current sink

Tags: operational-amplifier, constant-current, 4-20ma

[image]

The red circled part is acting as a constant current sink circuit but I can't understand how. If someone can share the calculations or formula or even explain what is happening?

Comment: IT uses positive feedback so, it's a little more complex than a "constant" current sink. Why not use a simulator and test it for yourself.

Comment: Can you tell us what U2 is? Both U2A and B have an output pull-up resistor, which suggests the device may not be a typical op-amp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any system with the structure below, will have the relationship \$V_{OUT}=V_{IN}\$ (barring any phase shift caused by system K):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIofnh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the classic application of a closed loop, whose goal is to "find and apply" whatever potential is necessary at G, to produce the condition \$V_{OUT}=V_{IN}\$, regardless of what K consists of. K could be anything, another amplifier, or a banana, and this system will settle with potential \$V_{OUT}\$ being equal to \$V_{IN}\$ (with the caveat that K doesn't introduce a phase shift that turns negative feedback into positive).

When K is a MOSFET configured as a source follower, we have this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvnt4K.png)</sup>

In this case the closed loop ensures that \$V_S=V_{IN}\$. That creates source current \$I_S\$ through R17:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_S &= \frac{V_S}{R_{17}} \\ \\
&= \frac{V_{IN}}{10\Omega}
\end{aligned}
$$

Since \$I_D=I_S\$, we have a current sink where \$I_D=\frac{V_{IN}}{10\Omega}\$.

In your circuit, this same principle is used, but there are a few small modifications to change the relationship \$V_S = V_{IN}\$ very slightly. I'll redraw your circuit with a few changes to make things clearer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHwnDt.png)</sup>

In the blue box is the Thevenin equivalent of the system composed of R15, R16 and the 5V supply. It behaves exactly the same as those original components, but allows us to find a value for \$V_{IN}\$, which is \$V_{IN}=+495mV\$.

I removed R31, since (if U2A is a normal op-amp) it makes no difference to behaviour whatsoever. R9 keeps gate charging current under control, and helps to stabilise the loop, but doesn't change the input/output relationship at all.

R11 is a little positive feedback, the purpose of which is not clear. However, I did the algebra, and found this relationship between \$V_S\$ and \$V_{IN}\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_S &= V_{IN} + V_{GS}\frac{R_{TH}}{R_{11}} \\ \\
&= 495mV + V_{GS}\frac{900\Omega}{200k\Omega}
\end{aligned}
$$

The only effect of R11 is to add a small offset \$V_{GS}\frac{900\Omega}{200k\Omega}\$. If we plug in the \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ for your MOSFET which (from the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd19532q5b.pdf)) I found to be +2.6V, we get:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_S &= 495mV + V_{GS}\frac{900\Omega}{200k\Omega} \\ \\
&= 495mV + 2.6V\times\frac{900\Omega}{200k\Omega} \\ \\
&= 0.507V
\end{aligned}
$$

Drain current \$I_D\$ will be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_D &= I_S \\ \\
&= \frac{V_S}{R_{17}} \\ \\
&= \frac{0.507V}{10\Omega} \\ \\
&= 50.7mA
\end{aligned}
$$

In my opinion, it is silly to use R11 (positive feedback) just to introduce a tiny offset of \$V_{GS}\frac{900\Omega}{200k\Omega}\$. If the designer wanted 50.7mA, why did he/she not simply adjust R15 or R16 to produce \$V_{IN}=+0.507V\$? Unless there's something special about U2A, or I'm missing something, R11 is not needed, and is maybe just a hack to increase \$I_D\$ very slightly after the system was already designed and built.

Comment: so the mosfet is working in ohmic region right?

Comment: @RachitJuthani Depends on which definition of "Ohmic" you use. I will say that the transistor is *not* saturated, nor is it cut-off. It is operating well within the linear, or active region, which by most accounts means Ohmic.

Answer (score 1):

R15 and R16 are maintaining a nominal 0.5 V reference voltage at the non-inverting input of U2A.

The amplifier, assuming a stable loop, will try to maintain the same voltage across R17 by controlling Q1.

0.5 V across 10Ω requires a current of 50 mA through R17, Q1, and whatever Q1 is sinking current from.

To be fair, I haven't wrapped my head around exactly what R11 is doing, or supposed to be doing. Is it acting as it first appears, to give +ve feedback as it's going to the non-inverting terminal of the opamp? Or does the loop's inversion means that it's overall negative feedback? If the feedback is positive, then it will tend to increase the reference voltage slightly and thus the output current as the FET requires more drive voltage, which might make sense if that's the desired behaviour. If overall negative, then it reduces the output impedance of the current source. Either way, R11 moves the output resistance of the current source, which should ideally be infinite, to either a positive or negative large value. In a standard, conventional, current source of this form, R11 would not be there. This change of output impedance is dependent on the VGS behaviour of the FET, which is very uncontrolled and temperature sensitive, so it's a bit of an odd inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the opamp being drawn in an unconventional orientation, it is the standard CC circuit in hundreds of application notes and websites, including this one:

[Parallel Transistors in Constant Current Load](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/146319/parallel-transistors-in-constant-current-load)

R17 is the current-sensing shunt.  Q1 drain (and source) current develops a voltage across this.  From the opamp's point of view, this voltage is the "output voltage" of the circuit.

It is fed back to the inverting input directly; that is, there are not the traditional two resistors setting the circuit gain.  Because of this, the entire circuit is operation as a voltage follower.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_amplifier#Voltage_buffer_examples

A voltage follower has unity gain.  The opamp will do whatever it takes at its output so that the voltage across R10 equals the voltage at its non-inverting input, pin 3.

The voltage at pin 3 is set by the circuit power supply (Vcc) and the resistor divider R15 and R16.  You can calculate the input voltage using Ohm's Law.

For example, if the input voltage is a constant 1 V, then the opamp will drive the FET such that the voltage across R10 is 1 V.  1 V / 10 ohms = 100 mA, and in this example that is the constant current load presented to the power source INT Pin2.